# Best way to split a huge file in Python

Tags: python

I need to split a very large file (3GB) ten times in the following way: the first split splits between the first 10% of the lines and the rest of the file, the second split splits between the second 10% of the lines and the rest and so on (This is in order to do cross validation)

I've done this naively by loading the lines of the file to a list,  going through the list and writing each line to the right output file by its index. This takes too long since it writes 3GB of data each time.

Is there a better way to do so?

Note: adding `#` to the start of each line is like deleting it. Would it be smarter to add and remove `#` to the start of the lines at the start?

EXAMPLE: if the file is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] then I want to split it like that:

```
[1] and [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[2] and [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[3] and [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and so on

Comment: Hmm.. If you are on a unix style system, you might be better off performing the split on the OS level... The [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) command can work by lines so you'll be able to have mostly even sized files (at least in number of lines).

Comment: so you want the file split up into 10 parts?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: please see the example

Comment: Some notes: whatever approach you take, you will still have to write 3GB of data; there is no way to split a file in-place.  Thus while you can speed up the userland side of things by using native OS tools, you're going to hit a lower bound defined by how fast your computer can do I/O.

Comment: Do you need `[1]` written to the file or in python memory? Do you need the subsequent `[2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10]` as well?

Comment: @roippi: Would the "#" trick not work?

Comment: @Matthew: Unfortunately I need them both as a text file

Comment: That means you're going to have to write 30 gb of data and any process writing that much data is going to take a long time... :/

Comment: I would do it simultaneously, using threading (https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) package. Just run you're logic in 10 concurrent threads.

Comment: The best way to make, it's to create a level of operating system 10 files ( each file 10% ), then in operating system level conveniently join them

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Thanks. This is what I did and the performance was better

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying to reduce the number of files. Even though 30 GB isn't too much with modern disks, it still takes a huge amount of effort (and time) to process.

For example:

- Assuming you want 10% of the lines, not 10% of the size, you could make an index file with the start of each line, and access the (single, original) text file through the index
- You could also convert the original file to a fixed record file, so that each text line occupies the same size. Then you could select access by using seek().

Both these functions could be 'hidden' by defining a file-like object in Python. That way you can access the single file as several 'virtual' files, each just showing the part (or parts) you want.